# Checking for a file of current date in remote server through unix shell script

Tags: unix

I've written a script that checks for a specific file of format("OLO2OLO_$DATE.txt.zip") in the ftp server and then copies it to my local machine:

```
/usr/bin/ftp -n 93.179.136.9 << !EOF!
user $USR $PASSWD
cd "/0009/Codici Migrazione"
get $FILE
bye
!EOF!

echo "$FILE"
```

But I'm not getting the desired result from this.

Comment: Your code seems ok. You didn't post your result, nor what exactly is your expected result? maybe you want to change the final "echo" for a "cat"

Comment: I want to check for the file if it's present and then download to my home directory.
                                                                                                                                      #!/bin/ksh
DATE=`date '+%y%m%d'`
FILE="OLO2OLO_$DATE_FATTURA.txt.zip"
SOURCE_FOLDER="/0009/"Codici Migrazione""
SOURCE_SERV="93.179.136.9"
fname="/0009/Codici Migrazione"
/usr/bin/ftp -n 93.179.136.9 << !EOF!
user IT0001 Armani
cd "/0009/Codici Migrazione"
get $FILE
bye
!EOF!
 Below is the error:
./code_mig[5]: Migrazione:  not found
Failed to open file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line triggers the error.

```
SOURCE_FOLDER="/0009/"Codici Migrazione""
```

It tries to execute the command `Migrazione` with the environment variable `SOURCE_FOLDER` set to `/0009/Codici` which doesn't exists.

What you probably wanted to do was:

```
SOURCE_FOLDER="/0009/Codici Migrazione"
```